# Conversion Error on LocalDate attribute when form-data request is sent to a Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I send a form-data request from the Postman to a spring application. The LocalDate field in the Spring application as a text field from the form-data. I got a Conversion Error.

```
@Column(
    name = "leasing_expiry",
    nullable = false
)
private LocalDate leasingExpiry;
```

> Field error in object 'vehicleDto' on field 'leasingExpiry': rejected value [2021-01-01]; codes [typeMismatch.vehicleDto.leasingExpiry,typeMismatch.leasingExpiry,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [vehicleDto.leasingExpiry,leasingExpiry]; arguments []; default message [leasingExpiry]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate' for property 'leasingExpiry'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank java.time.LocalDate] for value '2021-01-01'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2021-01-01]]

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOJ33.png)

Comment: Add Jackson  dependencies to your application and use @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
)annotation on your property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you have a problem with mapping `String` object into `LocalDate` object in Spring controller. Try annotate `LocalDate` field with following annotations:

```java
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
```

and following dependency might be required:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I was facing with the same problem some day and it solved my issue.

Comment: @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") adding this annotation also worked.